# XML POST and parse in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

If someone posts XML from an application to my ASP.NET page, how can I parse it and give the response back in XML format?

**Sample client code posting XML to my URL:**

```
WebRequest req = null;
WebResponse rsp = null;
string uri = "https://beta.abc.company.com/mypage.aspx";
req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
writer.WriteLine(txtXML.Text.ToString());
writer.Close();
rsp = req.GetResponse();
```

How could I parse XML from `mypage.aspx` and give the response as XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could read the XML from the request stream. So inside your `mypage.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventAgrs e)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // do something with the XML
    }
}
```

Comment: With that code inside a Web API Controller method, I get, "'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'InputStream' and no extension method 'InputStream' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

If the hint is a good one, what need I add?